# How to Add image in custom cell using settings.bundle in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5.1

i have created a settings screen for iPhone application which is visible in iPhone settings.
Now i have a requirement to add image logo of the application inside that screen (Screenshot Attached)

i am using root.plist for settings. any one guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Check the reference for the possible keys of root.plist http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/RootContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007018-SW1 and clarify the question.

Comment: i have read this, not even a single key tells how to put image into this.could you please guide me in bit more detail?

Comment: I mean there's nothing said in the docs about the icons other than the app icon will be used in the applications list. It usually means there's no allowed way to use the image there. For example twitter entry at Settings which has the icon and button is there out of of the box, so that feature is a part of iOs which is not always a public API, let me greet you at iOs land, Android stranger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up this problem with following points:

those applications that are part of iOS only display that functionality otherwise it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The icon displayed will be a scaled down version of the Icon.png file by default. If you want something different add an icon sized at 29 x 29 pixels named Icon-Settings.png to your application.

Comment: i am not talking about main settings screen icon but to put image icon into the inner screen of app settings like above screenshot.