# Customizing settings.bundle in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I want to make app settings using plist like the Twitter app settings and have my app name's status appear as "Installed" like done in Twitter.

Comment: Here is the answer given by A-Live read his comments. thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493405/how-to-add-image-in-custom-cell-using-settings-bundle-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your app in the twitter setting of settings app.
Well I sorry to tell you that that is not possible.

The twitter setting in the settings is build by apple to only detect the official twitter app.

If you just want you app under the settings app the read this: [Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Comment: No i dont want my app to appear in twitter app settings. but want my app to look like twitter app settings. hope you get my point.??

Comment: No I don't understand, there is only one option to get you app under the settings app and that is [adding the settings.bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html). Which wil only allow you to add standard element which you can't not style (except adding images to the sliders)

Comment: i have done other functionality as in twitter but just one thing remains. if you have seen twitter app settings, on the first inner page it shows twitter logo, and installed as status. so when i install my app should appear like twitter's.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is able to do that because Apple has included it as part of the OS core functionality. In other words, if Twitter is not installed then the Twitter settings are still available because Twitter can be used even with the app.

You can't do this with your app because if the app isn't installed then the settings won't appear anyway. Your settings will only show if the app is installed so saying 'installed' is redundant and unnecessary.